# Visual Studio 2017 can't find namespace System

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In one of my projects, Visual Studio says it can't find namespace System and similar Microsoft standard assemblies. It also can't load other projects in the other solution that it depends on.

To clarify, it DOES build, but pretty much every line in that project which references another project has a squiggly red "error" underlining.

When loading this solution, or when trying to add a dependency to this project (by right clicking Dependencies and selecting 'Add Reference...', I get this message:

> An element with the same key but a different value already exists.
>   Key: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp

The top of the csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> 

 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn)</NoWarn>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: .net Core web application, building to Framework 4.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` assembly was referenced twice in the .csproj, and removing the duplicate fixed the problem.

Comment: This can still bite you in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem few days back. Actually this problem occurs when you upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 and you try to run projects created on older version of VS.

1) First you have make the Target Framework equal for every module in the project.

2) Then you might have to upgrade Nuget packages with latest version for all modules.

3) Add missing references.

4) run VS as administrator, clean and build it again.

You will get the solution.